# Android studio bogging computer down recently

Tags: android-studio

I've been running Android Studio build 0.9 for a really long time (about 1.5 years) as I am a casual developer.

I needed an update to a few of my SDKs and repositories, so I decided I should update Android Studio as well.

I am now running Android Studio 1.5 and anytime I start up the program, for about 15 seconds I get huge FPS lag, and my CPU is at 100% usage. It returns back to normal after that.

Worse, when I go to generate a signed APK, such as one of my applications that is only 12MB in size, I get this same issue, but for like TWO MINUTES. It takes forever to generate my signed APK, and uses 100% of my CPU.

Is there something I can do to fix this? Thank you!

Edit: I am using an AMD Radeon FX-6300 processor (6 cores running at 3.5Ghz) if that helps. Edit2: I run 4GB of RAM.

Comment: how much RAM, and I'm guessing Windows?

Comment: I remember having slower operations due to accumulated apps on simulator devices.  It became so bad that I had to delete Android Studio entirely and reinstall.  Later, I realized there is an option to essentially reset your simulator devices (sorry do not recall right now) which clears any installed apps.